# How do I get a dictionary converted into DataFrame to show the columns I need?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to convert the data I've gathered in a dictionary through an API into a Pandas DataFrame but my output gives some random columns.

Here's my code:

```
# Dictionary for api data in 2015

data_2015 = dict()

all_dates_2015 = ['1/1/2015,2/1/2015', '2/2/2015,3/2/2015', '3/3/2015,4/3/2015',
       '4/4/2015,5/4/2015', '5/5/2015,6/5/2015', '6/6/2015,7/6/2015',
       '7/7/2015,8/7/2015', '8/8/2015,9/8/2015', '9/9/2015,10/9/2015',
       '10/10/2015,11/10/2015', '11/11/2015,12/11/2015']

for i in all_dates_2015:
    rr = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields??expr=AREA[LocationCountry]United%20States%20AND%20AREA[StudyFirstPostDate]RANGE[{}]%20AND%20AREA[OverallStatus]Recruiting&fields=NCTId,OverallStatus,Condition,InterventionName,LocationCity,LocationState,LocationCountry,BriefSummary&max_rnk=1000&fmt=json'.format(i))
    json_2015 = json.loads(rr.text)
    data_2015.update({i: json_2015}) 

df = pd.DataFrame(data_2015)
df
```

Here's what output I get:

[image: Output of the code]

I need a DataFrame with the output to be all the fields mentioned in the URL. When I print data_2015, it shows all the data that should be in the dataframe. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What the final dataframe should look like?

Comment: You are taking the json data and throwing it into the dict. You need to parse the json data, pull the values you want, and update each field

Comment: Instead of `rr.text`, you can just directly use `rr.json()`

Answer (score 1):

`pd.json_normalize` is a great tool for this type of situation.

I also made your url useable, so if you want to add/modify it... that'd be far simpler.

```
import urllib
import requests
import pandas as pd

data_2015 = {}
all_dates_2015 = ['1/1/2015,2/1/2015', '2/2/2015,3/2/2015', '3/3/2015,4/3/2015',
       '4/4/2015,5/4/2015', '5/5/2015,6/5/2015', '6/6/2015,7/6/2015',
       '7/7/2015,8/7/2015', '8/8/2015,9/8/2015', '9/9/2015,10/9/2015',
       '10/10/2015,11/10/2015', '11/11/2015,12/11/2015']

url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields'
for i in all_dates_2015:
    params = {'expr': ' AND '.join(["AREA[LocationCountry]United States", 
                                    f"AREA[StudyFirstPostDate]RANGE[{i}]", 
                                    "AREA[OverallStatus]Recruiting"]),
              'fields': ','.join(['NCTId', 'OverallStatus', 'Condition',
                                 'InterventionName', 'LocationCity', 
                                 'LocationState', 'LocationCountry', 
                                 'BriefSummary']),
              'max_rnk': 1000,
              'fmt': 'json'
             }
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    data = requests.get(url, params).json()
    df = pd.json_normalize(data['StudyFieldsResponse'], 
                           ['StudyFields'], 
                           ['APIVrs', 'DataVrs', 'Expression', 
                            'NStudiesAvail', 'NStudiesFound', 
                            'MinRank', 'MaxRank', 'NStudiesReturned'])
    data_2015.update({i: df})

dfs = pd.concat(data_2015).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
print(dfs)
print(dfs.columns)
```

Output:

```
                      index  Rank          NCTId             OverallStatus                                          Condition  ... NStudiesAvail NStudiesFound MinRank MaxRank NStudiesReturned
0         1/1/2015,2/1/2015     1  [NCT02335671]              [Recruiting]  [Early Stage Breast Cancer, Breast Cancer Stag...  ...        422349            67       1    1000               67
1         1/1/2015,2/1/2015     2  [NCT02348749]              [Recruiting]                            [Neuroendocrine Tumors]  ...        422349            67       1    1000               67
2         1/1/2015,2/1/2015     3  [NCT02347995]              [Recruiting]                                           [Stroke]  ...        422349            67       1    1000               67
3         1/1/2015,2/1/2015     4  [NCT02346435]              [Recruiting]                                  [Kidney Neoplasm]  ...        422349            67       1    1000               67
4         1/1/2015,2/1/2015     5  [NCT02344485]              [Recruiting]                [Parkinson's Disease, Constipation]  ...        422349            67       1    1000               67
...                     ...   ...            ...                       ...                                                ...  ...           ...           ...     ...     ...              ...
1124  11/11/2015,12/11/2015   113  [NCT02611323]  [Active, not recruiting]                           [Non-Hodgkin's Lymphoma]  ...        422349           117       1    1000              117
1125  11/11/2015,12/11/2015   114  [NCT02606136]  [Active, not recruiting]                      [Duchenne Muscular Dystrophy]  ...        422349           117       1    1000              117
1126  11/11/2015,12/11/2015   115  [NCT02627274]  [Active, not recruiting]  [Solid Tumor, Breast Cancer, Cancer of Head an...  ...        422349           117       1    1000              117
1127  11/11/2015,12/11/2015   116  [NCT02608268]  [Active, not recruiting]                            [Advanced Malignancies]  ...        422349           117       1    1000              117
1128  11/11/2015,12/11/2015   117  [NCT02612129]  [Active, not recruiting]                     [Niemann-Pick Disease, Type C]  ...        422349           117       1    1000              117

[1129 rows x 18 columns]

Index(['index', 'Rank', 'NCTId', 'OverallStatus', 'Condition',
       'InterventionName', 'LocationCity', 'LocationState', 'LocationCountry',
       'BriefSummary', 'APIVrs', 'DataVrs', 'Expression', 'NStudiesAvail',
       'NStudiesFound', 'MinRank', 'MaxRank', 'NStudiesReturned'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This just made my life so much easier!!